# how to use single partial view for different buttons in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc and i want to know how to use single partial view for different buttons in mvc

```html
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Aries')">Aries</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Taurus')">Taurus</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Gemini')">Gemini</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Cancer')">Cancer</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Leo')">Leo</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Virgo')">Virgo</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Libra')">Libra</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Scorpio')">Scorpio</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Sagittarius')">Sagittarius</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Capricorn')">Capricorn</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Aquarius')">Aquarius</button>
                    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Pisces')">Pisces</button>
```

i want a single partial view for this buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial view could just have `string` as its model:

```
@model string

<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '@Model')">@Model</button>
```

Use it like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_YourPartial", "Aries")
```